# How can I duplicate the result set like below

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below and I want to duplicate the records while the min date being less or equal the max date

```
686151209   E13232677   1333439 2017-10-23
686151209   E13232677   1333439 2017-10-26
```

I'd like to have the result set like below

```
686151209   E13232677   1333439 2017-10-23
686151209   E13232677   1333439 2017-10-24
686151209   E13232677   1333439 2017-10-25
86151209    E13232677   1333439 2017-10-26
```

Comment: do you have a dates table?

Comment: typo (missing 6) in the desired result?

Comment: which field set primary key or unique key in your table???

Comment: the columns number 1, 2 and 3 together

Comment: You can call them col1, col2, col3 and coldate

Comment: Having a date/calendar table makes this pretty easy. You'd have to create one. Here's a [good example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 1):

You and use spt_values to get continous number :

```
   ;WITH testdata(col1,col2,col3,col4)AS(
      SELECT '686151209','E13232677','1333439','2017-10-23' UNION all
      SELECT '686151209','E13232677','1333439','2017-10-26'
   )
   SELECT col1,col2,col3,DATEADD(d,sv.number-1,a.mindate) AS col4,sv.number FROM (
      SELECT col1,col2,col3,CONVERT(DATE,MIN(col4)) AS mindate,CONVERT(DATE,MAX(col4)) AS maxdate 
      FROM testdata AS t 
     group  by col1,col2,col3
   ) AS a 
   INNER JOIN master.dbo.spt_values AS sv ON sv.type='P' AND sv.number BETWEEN 1 AND DATEDIFF(d,mindate,maxdate)+1
```

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+--------+
| col1      | col2      | col3    | col4       | number |
+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+--------+
| 686151209 | E13232677 | 1333439 | 2017-10-23 | 1      |
| 686151209 | E13232677 | 1333439 | 2017-10-24 | 2      |
| 686151209 | E13232677 | 1333439 | 2017-10-25 | 3      |
| 686151209 | E13232677 | 1333439 | 2017-10-26 | 4      |
+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is a numbers table.  If you don't have too many rows, I also like a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select col1, col2, col3, mind, maxd
      from (select col1, col2, min(dte) as mind, max(dte) as maxd
            from t
            group by col1, col2, col3
           ) t
      union all
      select col1, col2, col3, dateadd(day, 1, mind), maxd
      from cte
      where  dateadd(day, 1, mind) < maxd
     )
select col1, col2, col3, mind
from cte;
```

This is limited to 100 rows for each `col1`/`col2` combination, unless you set the max recursion option.

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
    ID BIGINT,
    CODE VARCHAR(50),
    ID2 BIGINT,
    DATE DATE
);

INSERT INTO temp VALUES (686151209, 'E13232677', 1333439, '2017-10-23'),
                          (686151209, 'E13232677', 1333439, '2017-10-26');

SELECT generate_series(T.D1::timestamp, T.D2::timestamp, interval '1 day')::date
FROM
(
SELECT A.id, A.code, A.id2,  A.dates AS D1, B.dates  AS D2
FROM temp A
LEFT JOIN temp b ON (A.id = B.id AND
                      A.code=B.code AND
                      A.id2 = B.id2 AND
                      B.dates > A.dates)
WHERE B.id IS NOT NULL
) T;
```